# A question on recursion and transfinite recursion in extensions of KP

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Is the $\Sigma_{n}$-recursion supported by $\Sigma_{n}KP=KP+\Sigma_{n}$-separation + $\Sigma_{n}$-collection equivalent with $\Sigma_{n}$ transfinite recursion? If not, how do these notions differ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "$\Sigma_n$ recursion" and "$\Sigma_n$ transfinite recursion"?

Comment: Cfr. the answer to my question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/188214/a-question-on-recursion-in-kripke-platek-set-theory-with-infinity-and-sigma-3

Comment: And by "$\Sigma_n$ transfinite recursion" you mean the restriction to ordinals? Since both are consequences of $\Sigma_nKP$, what do you mean by "equivalent"?

Comment: By $\Sigma_{n}$ transfinite recursion I meant transfinite recursion restricted to $\Sigma_{n}$ functions. If both these are consequences of $\Sigma_{n}KP$, that is equivalent enough for me. :)